# Could not find package when running Ballerina code

Tags: ballerina

I have copy all the required jar files into /bre/lib/.

jar files were downloaded from here, https://github.com/wso2-ballerina/package-mongodb/releases/download/v0.5.5/wso2-mongodb-0.5.5.zip

Just simply import on the top of the code, still running into errors "could not find package wso2/mongodb:*"

```
import wso2/mongodb;
function main(string... args) {
  .......
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, this error is harmless even though it is very misleading. [1] has been reported to address this issue.

The reason behind this is, mongodb package is not at Ballerina Central yet. But, since you have copied the relevant jars to BALLERINA_HOME/bre/lib, the package not being pulled from Ballerina Central does not matter. **Ballerina code written using mongodb package will work.**

[1] https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/8314

Thanks

Comment: We'll fix this as soon as possible. If this answers your issue please mark as answer :)

Comment: This issue will be fixed in the next minor release.

Comment: @ShobhitSrivastava Please note that, the error message you get is harmless. As Natasha mentioned the plan is to fix the issue of printing this error message in an upcoming release. You should be able to use the package even though you get this error.

Comment: This issue is fixed now: https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/8314